# Using UNION to remove duplicate date but keep the same data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql

Halo All,

I hope you can help me. i'm using SQL Server.
I Have this XML data like this :

```
<Root>
  <Header>
    <refNo>S350282535-100060</refNo>
    <doNumber>0</doNumber>
  </Header>
  <Header>
    <refNo>S350282535-100061</refNo>
    <doNumber>1</doNumber>
  </Header>
  <Detail>
    <item>114495</item>
    <qty>2</qty>
    <uom>PC</uom>
    <refNo>S350282535-100060</refNo>
    <remarks>-</remarks>
    <reason>-</reason>
 </Detail>
 <Detail>
    <item>114496</item>
    <qty>2</qty>
    <uom>PC</uom>
    <refNo>S350282535-100061</refNo>
    <remarks>-</remarks>
    <reason>-</reason>
 </Detail>
 <Detail>
    <item>114497</item>
    <qty>2</qty>
    <uom>PC</uom>
    <refNo>S350282535-100061</refNo>
    <remarks>-</remarks>
    <reason>-</reason>
 </Detail>
</Root>
```

how i can get this kind of data :

```
refNo                    doNumber    Item      qty    uom
--------------------------------------------------------------------
S350282535-100060        0           114495     2     PC
S350282535-100061        1           114496     2     PC
S350282535-100061        1           114497     2     PC
```

here's my queries that i already have tried :

```
 DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX), @flagParameter AS 
 INT

 SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
 SET @flagParameter = 2

 SELECT item, qty,uom, refNo, remarks, reason
 FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Root/Detail',@flagParameter)
 WITH 
 (
  item [int],
  qty [int],
  uom [nvarchar] (6),
  refNo [nvarchar] (50),
  remarks [nvarchar] (100),
  reason [nvarchar] (100)
 )

SELECT refNo, doNumber
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Root/Header',@flagParameter)
WITH 
(
 refNo [nvarchar](50),
 doNumber [int]
)

SELECT refNo , doNumber, item--, qty,uom,  remarks, reason
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Root/Detail',@flagParameter)
WITH 
(
 refNo [nvarchar] (50),
 doNumber [int],
 item [int],
 qty [int],
 uom [nvarchar] (6),
 remarks [nvarchar] (100),
 reason [nvarchar] (100)
)

UNION

SELECT refNo, doNumber, One as Item--, two as two, three as three, four as 
four
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Root/Header',@flagParameter)
WITH 
(
 refNo [nvarchar](50),
 doNumber [int],
 one [int],
 two [int],
 three [int],
 four [int]
) EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

i use UNION, but the result was not as my expected, does any one can help me?i'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Would you please share your UNION query that you are trying?

Comment: yes, sure @keyur :

Comment: i added my queries at my post. @keyur

Comment: I think you need a join or cross apply instead of a UNION. Please check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346409/matching-one-attribute-to-another-using-xpath-xquery-in-sql-server-2008   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827126/how-to-join-openxml-data-to-my-inner-join-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the XML data is stored in an XML variable named `@xml` :

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<Root>
  <Header>
    <refNo>S350282535-100060</refNo>
    <doNumber>0</doNumber>
  </Header>
  <Header>
    <refNo>S350282535-100061</refNo>
    <doNumber>1</doNumber>
  </Header>
  <Detail>
    <item>114495</item>
    <qty>2</qty>
    <uom>PC</uom>
    <refNo>S350282535-100060</refNo>
    <remarks>-</remarks>
    <reason>-</reason>
 </Detail>
 <Detail>
    <item>114496</item>
    <qty>2</qty>
    <uom>PC</uom>
    <refNo>S350282535-100061</refNo>
    <remarks>-</remarks>
    <reason>-</reason>
 </Detail>
 <Detail>
    <item>114497</item>
    <qty>2</qty>
    <uom>PC</uom>
    <refNo>S350282535-100061</refNo>
    <remarks>-</remarks>
    <reason>-</reason>
 </Detail>
</Root>'
```

the following is one possible way to get the expected result using [XML methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods) and XPath/XQuery instead of the older OPENXML :

```
;WITH Header(refNo, doNumber)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        T.C.value('refNo[1]', 'varchar(100)')
        ,T.C.value('doNumber[1]', 'int')
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/Header') AS T(C)
)

SELECT 
    Header.*
    ,T.C.value('item[1]', 'varchar(100)') 'item'
    ,T.C.value('qty[1]', 'int') 'qty'
    ,T.C.value('uom[1]', 'varchar(100)') 'uom'
FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/Detail') AS T(C)
INNER JOIN Header on T.C.value('refNo[1]', 'varchar(100)') = refNo
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://rextester.com/CCA61219)</kbd>**

Comment: @AgusmanPriantoro you are welcome. Since you've never done it so far, I would remind you to consider [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved the problem in question.